# Filtering in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, zend-framework, filter, propel

I am filtering a store in extjs:

So far so good, the Problem I have that's not matter if the function returns `true` or `false`, the entity still stay in my store.

Thanks for your Help,
Daniel

Comment: Are you using Ext.form.field.Date for filter input? If yes, try to parse date.

Comment: Provide json data as well which type of data you are using.

Comment: Try without Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('krankmeldungstore').load();

Comment: Thanks @Zhorov, it worked without the .load() function at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ext.getStore('xxx').filterBy()** works locally on the data retrieved from the proxy. So if you fire **Ext.getStore('xxx').load()** or **Ext.getStore('xxx').reload()** this will wipe the local filtered data with the data retrieved from the server.

You can also use **Ext.getStore('xxx').load({params:{'param1':'value1'}})** to make the filtration from the server side.

Now note that if you want to use the same params again you can just call **Ext.getStore('xxx').reload()** and now this is equal to **Ext.getStore('xxx').load({params:{'param1':'value1'}})**. But if you use **Ext.getStore('xxx').load()** it is like you are sending no parameters to the server.

***Finally*** you should first use **Ext.getStore('xxx').load({params:{'param1':'value1'}})** or **Ext.getStore('xxx').load()** to get your data from the server then use filterBy to apply a local filter to the retrieved data.

*NB: I am assuming you are using ajax or rest proxy not local proxies*